# dictionary key as line number to read text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file that contains a unique text like vrf_name: **nVSatellite that has been stored in a dictionary. In between, one vrf_name to upcoming vrf_name contains a set of lines this line I need to parse in a list 
please provide me the solution.

VRF: **nVSatellite

```
 L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120
 C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122
```

VRF: ePDG-IN

```
    L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120
 C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122
```

VRF: JKIT-TL

```
   L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120
 C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122
```

VRF: MST-LKAS

```
 .
 .
 .
 .

 dict = {}
  for index, line in enumerate(read_file()):
      match1 = re.search(r"VRF:", line)
      if match1:
          dict[index] = line
```

expected outcome:
     line present in between VRF: need to be parsed in a list

Comment: I see answer was deleted few miunutes ago, maybe help [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) . Also dont forget add some code, what you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear exactly what your input file looks like, and what you want to save from it.

By the way, you want to avoid using `dict` as a variable name. It is a built-in type.

Assuming an input like like this - `vrf_textfile.txt`:

```
VRF: **nVSatellite
 L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120
 C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122

VRF: ePDG-IN
 L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120
 C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122

VRF: JKIT-TL
 L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120
 C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120
 O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122
```

Code:

```
with open(r"vrf_textfile.txt") as f:
    vrf_text = f.read() # This is read in as a single long string

vrf = {}
current_key = None

for index, line in enumerate(vrf_text.splitlines()):
    if line.startswith("VRF:"):
        vrf[index] = []
        current_key = index
    elif current_key is not None:
        if line.strip() != "": # I assume you don't want to include blank lines
            vrf[current_key].append(line)

# vrf is a dictionary of lists. Every key is a line number (int)
for line_number, lists in vrf.items():
    for item in lists:
        print(f"{line_number} - '{item}'")
```

Output:

```
0 - ' L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120'
0 - ' C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120'
0 - ' L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120'
0 - ' O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122'
6 - ' L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120'
6 - ' C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120'
6 - ' L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120'
6 - ' O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122'
12 - ' L    10.61.0.252/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether100.120'
12 - ' C    10.61.76.240/31 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120'
12 - ' L    10.61.76.240/32 is directly connected, 9w5d, Bundle-Ether50.120'
12 - ' O    223.224.150.16/32 [110/12] via 10.61.0.230, 5w4d, Bundle-Ether200.122'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

d = {}

with open('vrf.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    expr = re.compile(r'VRF:')
    first_match = None
    first_index = -1
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        next_match = expr.match(line)
        if next_match:
            if first_match:
                d[first_index] = lines[first_index: index]
            first_match = next_match
            first_index = index
```